# How to get the list of failed Agent pool jobs for the last 7 days in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-agent

How to get the extended list of failed jobs when the incident occured since I can see only failed jobs for today.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can see only failed jobs today, please check if you are setting the retention policy-> Project Settings -> under Pipeline -> Settings
[image: Retention policy] and try to use the following REST API to list the jobs

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organiztion}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/jobrequests
```

If there are more than 7 days jobs shows, you could use the PowerShell script to filter the failed jobs.